# How to debug statement with "await"

Tags: playwright

There are many ways to debug the playwright.
But I have not found a way about how to execute a statement in debugger or anywhere in other place during debugging which is asynchronous (with await) statement.

e.g. While debugging the test case using VSCODE extention, if I execute the statement await this.page.locator('.acceptTerms') in DEBUG console, then it shows the statement in pending promise which gets never resolved.

Found the same issue during other debugging method too.

Is there any way that during debug when there is a breakpoint at any place, we can execute statements with await statement and can get it resolved with value.

This helps a lot to debug and execute statements during debugging.

Tried to use watch section too, but its same result.